# Create a link from MS Teams for third parties to call me via videocall

Tags: microsoft-teams, call

How do I create a link for third parties (company-externals) in order for them to call me via video call in teams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL can initiate a call to a specified user :

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=username@domain.com

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Who would have thought that? Can't believe that it took me and ChatGPT one hour to NOT find that information beforehand.